# Android JCIFS Failed to establish session

Tags: java, android, jcifs

I found a strange situation. I use in my projects jcifs-1.3.18.jar for read files in the local network.

```
String url_file = "smb://10.0.0.55/hermes_lite/ttt.txt";
SmbFile smb_file;
boolean b = false;
try
{         
  smb_file = new SmbFile(url_file);         
  try
  {
     b = smb_file.exists();            
  }
  catch(SmbException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
catch(MalformedURLException e1)
{
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

When the program starts, I check the files for the first time. I also checked the files when WiFi is connected (via BroadCastReceiver).
If first time on "smb_file.exists()" instruction i will have exception (Exception - Network unreachable, when WiFi still not connected), second and following "smb_file.exists()" instructions also throw exception 
but already "Failed to establish session". The exception continues to occur until I kill the app in recent task list.

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: WORKGROUP<00>/10.0.0.55
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.io.IOException: Failed to establish session with WORKGROUP<00>/10.0.0.55
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.ssn139(SmbTransport.java:239)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:249)
...
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue in jcifs, use host name instead of IP (you can review network traffic, filtered by port 139, observing "Called name is required" message from target machine).

From my experience, IP is working fine unless you interrupt network connection (cable disconnect) on target machine.

Thanks